# Why spark's global_temp database not visible?

Tags: apache-spark

With the new `createGlobalTempView` in Spark 2.1.0, it is possible to share a table amongst multiple spark sessions

However, this database can't be accessible from the outside. For example :

```
scala> spark.sql("select * from global_temp.salaries")
res240: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [yearID: string, teamID: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> salaries.createGlobalTempView("salaries")

scala> spark.sql("select * from global_temp.salaries").show(5)
+------+------+----+---------+------+
|yearID|teamID|lgID| playerID|salary|
+------+------+----+---------+------+
|  1985|   ATL|  NL|barkele01|870000|
|  1985|   ATL|  NL|bedrost01|550000|
|  1985|   ATL|  NL|benedbr01|545000|
|  1985|   ATL|  NL| campri01|633333|
|  1985|   ATL|  NL|ceronri01|625000|
+------+------+----+---------+------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Nothing is wrong here, but here comes the strange behaviour

```
scala> spark.catalog.listTables.show
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|name|database|description|tableType|isTemporary|
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+

scala> spark.catalog.tableExists("global_temp","salaries")
res249: Boolean = true
```

My guess is that `global_temp` database is hidden for all users, but it is possible to query tables on it if we already know wich table to query.

Is it a normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for any explanaitions

Answer (score 2):

When you run `spark.catalog.listTables.show` , if you don't specify the database for the listTables() function it will point to `default` database.

Try this instead:

```
spark.catalog.listTables("global_temp").show
```

It's definitely not hidden for all users, quite the opposite. It will only be visible while your spark session is running, but will be visible to other spark sessions running simultaneously, for example a colleague running their own spark-shell on the same cluster & catalog setup.